# Can't fetch all users

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

So, I made a discord bot, and I am sitting in front of a problem now. I need to give every user a role.

So, I googled and got some answers, but none of them work. Everytime I get the bot to run without errors, it just does it for a couple users of the server, and not for all of them.

I tried to fix this problem since 1 week now, any help is very apprechiated!

Comment: We're not gonna help you if you don't provide code or an error about the problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help you, we need certain information, like code and error(s). Please see [ask] and [edit] your question to fit those standards

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const members = await message.guild.members.fetch();

members // return full list of users, must have member intents in dev portal, hope it can fix your problem
```